# How to convert all bytes files under the folder into images

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image
import binascii

def getMatrixfrom_bin(filename,width):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
    ...
    return fh

filename = "path\bin_filename(1)"
im = Image.fromarray(getMatrixfrom_bin(filename,512))
//getMatrixfrom_bin () is a function that generates a matrix from the binary bytes
im.save("path\bin_filename(1).png")
```

The code  above can only generate a picture at a time, now I need to convert all the binary files under the path to images, how should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a decent (i.e. Unix/Linux/macOS) platform, you can convert all your binary files to PNG images in parallel without writing any Python, if you use **GNU Parallel** and **ImageMagick** which are installed on most Linux distros and are available for macOS via **homebrew**.

So, the command to convert all files ending in `.bin` into `PNG` images, in parallel would be:

```
parallel 's=$(wc -c < {}); w=512; ((h=s/w)); convert -depth 8 -size ${w}x${h} gray:{} {.}.png' ::: *bin
```

That is a bit scary if you are not accustomed to it, so I'll break it down. Basically it is running *"some stuff"* in parallel for all files ending in `.bin`, so look again and it is:

```
parallel 'some stuff' ::: *.bin
```

What is the *"some stuff"*? Well, note that `{}` is short-hand for the file we are currently processing, so it is doing this:

```
s=$(wc -c < {})         # s=total bytes in current file, i.e. s=filesize
w=512                   # w=image width
((h=s/w))               # h=s/w, i.e. h=height in pixels of current file
convert ...
```

The last line, the one starting `convert` is calling **ImageMagick** telling it your image depth is 8 bits, and the dimensions in pixels are WxH, it is then reading the current file into an image and saving it as a new image ending in `PNG` instead of the original extension. Easy!

---

Of course, if you knew the width was 500 pixels and the height was 400 pixels, life would be even easier:

```
parallel 'convert -depth 8 -size 500x400 gray:{} {.}.png' ::: *bin
```